# Difference between “::” “.” and “->” in c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have found the class Kwadrat. The author used three types of operator ::, . and ->. The arrow is the one that only works. What's the difference between those three?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Kwadrat{
public:
int val1, val2, val3;
    Kwadrat(int val1, int val2, int val3)
    {
        this->val1 = val1;
        //this.val2 = val2;
        //this::val3 = val3;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Kwadrat* kwadrat = new Kwadrat(1,2,3);
    cout<<kwadrat->val1<<endl;
    cout<<kwadrat->val2<<endl;
    cout<<kwadrat->val3<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any C++ book or tutorial could answer this.

Comment: The OP must be trying to learn C++ the hard way. Don't.

Comment: `::` is the scope resolution operator.  If I say `a::b` it means I'm talking about the `b` inside of `a` whether `a` is a namespace or a class, and whether `b` is a function, variable, class, namespace, whatever.

Answer (score 6):

- `::` names a type within a namespace, a variable within a namespace, a static variable in a class, or a type in a class.
- `.` names an instance variable or member function
- `a->b` is syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`.

Comment: Generally speaking, `a->b` may *also* be syntactic sugar for an overloaded `operator->` of the class of which `a` is an instance.

Comment: @Nik: Of course; but if the OP is struggling with this I didn't want to throw in how crazy `operator->` works :)

Answer (score 0):

`->` works on pointers, `.` on objects and `::` on namespaces. Specifically:

1. Use `->` or `.` when accessing a class/struct/union member, in the first case through a pointer, in the latter through a reference.
2. Use `::` to reference the function inside a `namespace` or a `class` (namespaces), for instance, when defining methods declared with the class.

Comment: A class is a namespace too. I did not write `namespace` purposely.

Answer (score 0):

`x->y` is equivalent to `(*x).y`.  That is, `->` dereferences the variable before getting the field while the dot operator just gets the field.

`x::y` looks up y in namespace x.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete since `::` (the 'scope' operator) also accesses static members of a class.

Answer (score 0):

The use cases are:

1. `->` is used when you have a pointer
2. `.` is used when you have an object instance
3. `::` is used when you have a static member or a namespace

Comment: There's no such thing as a static class.

Comment: I mean a static member sorry

Answer (score 0):

The -> is the equivalent of saying (*Kwadrat_pointer).value. You use it when you have an object pointer calling object methods or retrieving object members.

The . operator is used to access the methods and members in the object that is calling it (that is, the object on the left side of the ".").

The :: operator is called the scope operator. It tells your program where to look, for example when defining a class method outside of the class declaration.